# BeanInitializationException with NPE during initialization when branching with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am currently working on an application using Spring Cloud Stream framework and I'm having troubles upgrading kafka deprecated method [KStream.branch()](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#branch) to [KStream.split()](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#split()). I used to seperate my KStream input in several KStreams using branch() with predicates and then apply several business logic to these streams but now I encounter a BeanInitializationException during the initialization of my tests such as :

```
15:31:48.425 [main] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaStreamsFunctionProcessorInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Cannot setup function invoker for this Kafka Streams function.; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream.toTable()" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
15:31:48.465 [main] ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaStreamsFunctionProcessorInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Cannot setup function invoker for this Kafka Streams function.; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream.toTable()" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
                at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
```

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```
@Bean
public BiFunction<
        KStream<Integer, Integer>,
        KTable<String, String>,
        KStream<Integer, Integer>>
    process() {
        return (inputA, inputB) -> {
            
            Map<String, KStream<Integer, Integer>> mapInputA = inputA
                .split()
                .branch((key, value) -> value > 50,     // Some business predicates
                    Branched.as("branchOver50"))
                .defaultBranch(Branched.as("branchUnder50"));
            
            mapInputA
                .get("branchOver50")
                .toTable(                     // <- BeanCreationException (NPE : map.get() is null)
                    Named.as("KTable_Over_50"),
                    Materialized.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Integer())
                ).join(
                    inputB,
                    ...
```

From my understanding, I encounter a NullPointerException during initialization because the map is empty since there is no data yet, but since the deprecated method KStream.branch() didn't require any action to handle empty streams, I was wondering if this was an intended behavior of the new method KStream.split() or if I was doing something wrong.

The error happens during a JUnit test using an EmbeddedKafkaBroker to simulate the Kafka environment (I am using kafka-streams version 3.0.0).

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can check `containsKey` on the map. Or, why not give `Named.as` like the docs show?

Comment: I know I can avoid this error by testing on the map, but my question was more about if it was an intended behavior to test if the map has the key since the previous implementation of branch() which returned an array of kstreams actually initialized these kstreams even with no data, avoiding NPE issues.

Comment: I think you should test the map if you want to get a specific named topic/branch. I see no other way the code will run to completion if the consumer reads no messages, or if you had some typo in the Predicate that made it wrong, for example

Comment: Not entirely sure what the issue is. Since you mentioned branching, [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/function/KafkaStreamsBinderWordCountBranchesFunctionTests.java#L202) is how we modified some branching tests in the binder framework. See if those changes ring any bells in your scenario. Feel free to create a reproducible small sample, if you still have issues and share with us.

Comment: I guess I will have to test for each .branch(Predicate) before using them. I was just surprised that the map didn't contain an initialized empty KStream for each branching, as the previous `KStream.branch(Predicate)` did with the KStream array.